# InnerJoin no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou trabalhando em um código e preciso fazer uma associação, aonde tenho que contar a quantidade de votação em um vídeo. O problema é que são 2 tabelas a de **videos** e **votacoes** . Em `videos` fica os vídeos cadastrados, e lá tem o *id* do vídeo e o link. Em `votacoes` tem o *id_video* e quem votou. Estou usando CodeIgniter para fazer a consulta e listar os vídeos:

Controller:

```
class Promocao extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('miss_model', 'miss');
    }


    public function votacao($id = NULL) {

/* Pega os vídeos */
        $data['videos'] = $this->miss->find_all('id', 'desc');
        $data['titulo'] = 'Votação - TOP CLASS VIP';
        $this->load->view('votacao', $data);

    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php if (count($videos)):foreach ($videos as $row):?>
    <div class="col-md-4">    
        <video width="240" height="240" controls>
            <source src="<?php echo base_url('assets/videos/miss/' . $row['video'])?>" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="<?php echo base_url('assets/videos/miss/' . $row['video'])?>" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>

        <?php echo anchor('promocao/votacao/' . $row['id'], 'VOTAR', 'class="btn btn-success"');?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php else:?>
    <h1 class="text-center">SEM VÍDEOS</h1>
<?php endif;?>
```

No **view** eu preciso colocar assim **30 votos** por exemplo, ou seja, exibir a quantidade de votos obtidos de cada vídeo. O problema é que não sei como relacionar as duas tabelas pela **id** do vídeo e **id_video** da outra tabela.

Comment: Veja o [manual como usar join](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html).

Comment: Desculpe, é **view** irei arrumar.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, para fazer join no CI é assim:
dentro da model que herda a model do CI

```
public function listaVideos()
{
   return $this->db->select("videos.*, votacoes.voto")
               ->join("votacoes", "votacoes.id_video=videos.id")
               ->get("videos")->result();
}
```

é mais ou menos isso
uma referencia boa também é a própria documentação:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select